# Problemas con file_put_contents PHP

Tags: php

Tengo un problema con esa función, a veces guarda la imagen, otras veces no y no sé por qué, he hecho de todo y nada. ¿Alguién me podría ayudar?

Aquí el código.

```
<?php
  $croped_image = $_POST['dataImage'];
  list($type, $croped_image) = explode(';', $croped_image);
  list(, $croped_image) = explode(',', $croped_image);
  $croped_image = base64_decode($croped_image);
  $image_name = time().'.png';
  //Guardamos la imagen
  file_put_contents('../eventos/'.$image_name, $croped_image);
?>
```

Comment: En SO debes mostrar el codigo como texto ya que nosotros copiar y ejecutar el codigo de forma rapida y sencilla.

Comment: Cuando no te guarda la imagen, ¿aparece algún error en los logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El formato de un `dataURI` es

```
data:[<mime type>][;charset=<charset>][;base64],<encoded data>
```

Por lo tanto puede haber 0, 1 o 2 caracteres `;`.

Yo en tu lugar haría un split por una expresión regular asumiendo que el último elemento del array es la data misma:

```
<?php
$dataUri ='data:[<mime type>][;charset=<charset>][;base64],<encoded data>';

$exploded_uri = preg_split("/[,;]+/",$dataUri);

$encoded_data = array_pop($exploded_uri);

print_r($encoded_data);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! me funcionó igual, logré encontrar el error :)